# Running FaceSubStitution and ScrambleSuit on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, openframeworks

I'm trying to build and run a popular app called FaceSubstitution that does face morphing through camera, OpenFrameworks and OpenCV: https://github.com/arturoc/FaceSubstitution

I've been at it for some days now but I don't understand the directions on the Github page at all. After downloading Open Frameworks, I can get an openFrameworks project to build and run on XCode, but am I supposed to keep working within that project file and add OfxCV and OfxFaceTracker as addons to that same project using XCode? (Just moving OfxCV and OfxFaceTracker libs and src folders into XCode on top of that Open Frameworks project?)

Would appreciate any tutorials that help with just understanding how to work with Open Frameworks in general. Btw, I'm an iOS Developer and trying to integrate Open Frameworks and OpenCV into iOS Projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by building upon an existing project. You should copy the project from the addons or examples folder and paste it into apps/myApps rather than altering the existing app. From here you can add addons to the project as you go.

Alternatively you can start from scratch by either making a copy of the emptyExample in examples/empty or, even better, using the project generator (look in the root). From here you can select the addons you need, name the project, and select the folder you want to save it to.

There are a lot of great tutorials and resources on the OF site. You should go through the [introduction section](http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/).